# How do you properly breakpoint a card deck in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, asp.net, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

I've seen a couple similar questions, but none of them seem to address cards that are generated. My goal is to have 4 or less cards per row, at a fixed height/width. Below is the code I currently have:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card-deck">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="card shadow">
                <div class="card-title pl-4 pr-4 pt-3">
                    <h4><a class="stretched-link deco-none font-weight-bold" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="TrainingDetails" asp-route-id="@item.TrainingId">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</a></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body overflow pl-4 pr-4 pb-2">
                    <div class="font-weight-bold text-secondary">
                        @Convert.ToDateTime(item.DateCreated).ToString("MM/dd/yy")
                    </div>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <div class="text-center text-muted training-footer">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Topic.Topic)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently it puts all the cards on a single row, and each card itself is incredibly thin. What do I have to add to get it to break off into multiple rows of fixed size?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bootstrap’s grid system with [row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/card/#grid-cards) to define how many cards in a row at each breakpoint. All of the cards will be the same height.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
<div class="container mt-5">
   <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-lg-3">
      <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card shadow h-100">
               <div class="card-title pl-4 pr-4 pt-3">
                  <h4><a class="stretched-link deco-none font-weight-bold" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="TrainingDetails" asp-route-id="TrainingRoute">First Title</a></h4>
               </div>
               <div class="card-body overflow pl-4 pr-4 pb-2">
                  <div class="font-weight-bold text-secondary">
                        03/21/21
                  </div>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
               </div>
               <div class="card-footer">
                  <div class="text-center text-muted training-footer">
                        Last updated 7 days ago
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card shadow h-100">
               <div class="card-title pl-4 pr-4 pt-3">
                  <h4><a class="stretched-link deco-none font-weight-bold" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="TrainingDetails" asp-route-id="TrainingRoute">Second Title</a></h4>
               </div>
               <div class="card-body overflow pl-4 pr-4 pb-2">
                  <div class="font-weight-bold text-secondary">
                        03/22/21
                  </div>
                  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
               </div>
               <div class="card-footer">
                  <div class="text-center text-muted training-footer">
                        Last updated 6 days ago
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card shadow h-100">
               <div class="card-title pl-4 pr-4 pt-3">
                  <h4><a class="stretched-link deco-none font-weight-bold" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="TrainingDetails" asp-route-id="TrainingRoute">Third Title</a></h4>
               </div>
               <div class="card-body overflow pl-4 pr-4 pb-2">
                  <div class="font-weight-bold text-secondary">
                        03/24/21
                  </div>
                  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
               </div>
               <div class="card-footer">
                  <div class="text-center text-muted training-footer">
                        Last updated 5 days ago
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card shadow h-100">
               <div class="card-title pl-4 pr-4 pt-3">
                  <h4><a class="stretched-link deco-none font-weight-bold" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="TrainingDetails" asp-route-id="TrainingRoute">Fourth Title</a></h4>
               </div>
               <div class="card-body overflow pl-4 pr-4 pb-2">
                  <div class="font-weight-bold text-secondary">
                        03/25/21
                  </div>
                  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
               </div>
               <div class="card-footer">
                  <div class="text-center text-muted training-footer">
                        Last updated 4 days ago
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card shadow h-100">
               <div class="card-title pl-4 pr-4 pt-3">
                  <h4><a class="stretched-link deco-none font-weight-bold" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="TrainingDetails" asp-route-id="TrainingRoute">Fifth Title</a></h4>
               </div>
               <div class="card-body overflow pl-4 pr-4 pb-2">
                  <div class="font-weight-bold text-secondary">
                        03/26/21
                  </div>
                  Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
               </div>
               <div class="card-footer">
                  <div class="text-center text-muted training-footer">
                        Last updated 3 days ago
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card shadow h-100">
               <div class="card-title pl-4 pr-4 pt-3">
                  <h4><a class="stretched-link deco-none font-weight-bold" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="TrainingDetails" asp-route-id="TrainingRoute">Sixth Title</a></h4>
               </div>
               <div class="card-body overflow pl-4 pr-4 pb-2">
                  <div class="font-weight-bold text-secondary">
                        03/27/21
                  </div>
                  Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.
               </div>
               <div class="card-footer">
                  <div class="text-center text-muted training-footer">
                        Last updated 2 days ago
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```